# Can a negative local martingale start from 0?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

In a recent paper that I've found it is written that if $M_t$ is a local martingale such that $M_0=0$ and $M_t<0$ for all $t>0$ then this is a contradiction.

I don't see why. How this can be true?

Comment: what's the definition of "local martingale" again???

Comment: There must be stopping times such that $E[M_T] = 0$.  But $M_T < 0$ almost surely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X:=-M$ is then a non-negative local martingale, let's say localized by the sequence $(T_n)$ of stopping times. You have $0=\Bbb E[X_0]=\Bbb E[X_{t\wedge T_n}]$ for each $n\ge 1$ and $t>0$, by optional stopping. Now let $n\to\infty$ and use Fatou's lemma; conclusion: $\Bbb E[X_t]=0$ for each $t>0$.

Comment: Complete answer! Got it!